# Parsing two parts of YouTube JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch, youtube

I have the following youtube JSON which I am trying to parse so that I can access things like the title, description, etc...
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=remedyLIVE&max-results=5&v=2&alt=jsonc&orderby=published

Right now I am putting it in a dictionary where it returns two value/key pairs. One is for the api and the other one is EVERYTHING else.

I will attach my code below but I know it is close but just not quite right. Could anyone provide a specific example on how to parse this json? I cannot find any good examples on how this is done, so if someone could help me access these values that would be awesome. I have spent countless hours reading JSON tutorials but I still can't figure it out on how it applies to what I am doing. Thank you!!

```
    NSURL *youtubeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=remedyLIVE&max-results=5&v=2&alt=jsonc&orderby=published"];


    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:youtubeURL];
        if (data == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"data is nil");
        }
        else
        {
            NSError *error;
            titleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            videoIDArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            thumbArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

            videoDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
            NSLog(@"%@", videoDictionary);




        }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: [image]

```
+(void)json{

NSURL *youtubeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=remedyLIVE&max-results=5&v=2&alt=jsonc&orderby=published"];


NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:youtubeURL];
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *dic_JSON =
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data
                                options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                  error: &error];




}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example.

```
NSDictionary *subDict = [videoDictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
if (subDict) {
    NSArray *subArray = [subDict objectForKey:@"items"];
    if ([subArray count]) {
        for (NSDictionary *dictItem in subArray) {
            NSString *title = [dictItem objectForKey:@"title"];
            NSString *description = [dictItem objectForKey:@"description"];
            NSLog(@"title is %@, description is %@", title, description);
        }
    }
}
```